# Is it possible to get a YouTube audio stream in Web Audio's MediaElementAudioSourceNode?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, web-audio-api

I want to be able to load only the audio stream of the youtube video and process it (EQ, Effects, etc.) through a graph of Web Audio nodes.

Is this doable? Any open-source work out there, doing that?

Thanks in advance to all and any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because you can't get audio streams cross-domain.  (that is, if your code could be hosted on YouTube.com, sure, but not from mydomain.com.)

The reason for this (you CAN do it if CORS is set up, but it's not on YouTube) is because if you can get the audio stream, you can do a bit-copy of the data.  Just like images, they don't want to leak the raw data.

Comment: What about a Chrome extension?

Comment: Probably?  https://developer.chrome.com/apps/xhr#extension-origin seems to imply so if you ask for the right permissions.  I've never tried this, though.